# Why does calling classList add/remove not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html code: (aside part is hidden as it is a curtain menu)

```
    <body id="Body" onscroll="setTimeout(checkforscroll, 100);">
        <div class="first" id="first">
            <aside id="menu">
                ...
            </aside>
            <header id="header">
                <div class="flex common">
                    <a onclick="openMenu()" class="hamburger"><img src="Images/more.png"></a>
                    <a href="#first"><img src="Images/ubereats.svg"></a>
                    <a class="button1" href=""><img src="Images/profile.png">Log in</a>
                    <a class="button2" href="">Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </header>
```

and CSS parts are:

```
header{
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* z-index: 0; */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: none;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.mystyle{
    background-color: white;
}
.mystyle1{
    background-color: none;
}
```

and the JavaScript part is:

```
function checkforscroll() {
    // var changebgs = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
    let y = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(y);
    if(y > 0){
        document.getElementById("header").classList.remove("myStyle1");
        document.getElementById("header").classList.add("myStyle");
        console.log("white");
        //list.add("myStyle");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("header").classList.remove("myStyle");
        document.getElementById("header").classList.add("myStyle1");
        console.log("none");
    }

}
```

I want the header to change colour to white as soon as scroll value>0 and return to being transparent when scroll value is <=0.

I tries various different approaches, but always the colour changed to white correctly, but never ever returned back to being transparent.

Comment: what error message do you get? `TypeReference Error: Element is Null`? Properly caused by the line `list.add(...)` which should cause an error as `list` is not defined and `add` is not allowed function within that syntax.

Comment: I don't get any error message. The background colour just doesn't revert to being transparent. Oh, and the list.add part was commented out

Comment: I am not sure how CSS calculates the most important definitions in detail, but this will probably be solved if you define them as `header.mystyle` and `header.mystyle2`. By adding header to these their importance gets equalised with the regular `header` definition, and then adds even more importance due to the classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just made a simple error of not capitalising the 'S' in mystyle(1) classes in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a capital letter (S) the in javascript "myStyle1" and "myStyle" while in the css you have the class all in lower case ".mystyle" and ".mystyle1"